# "530 Valid hostname is expected." when connecting to FTP site in IIS

Tags: ftp, windows-server-2012-r2, iis-8

I have created a FTP site in IIS where I configured a host header. I know that to connect to the FTP account I need to use "host|username" syntax, but that does not work in my case when I try to connect using FtpConnection methods in a software I developed.

Is there a way to just pass the user without the hostname?

Answer (score 1):

Your issue has to do with how IIS handles incomming requests. 
You might want to take a look at:
[MSDN blog-post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/robert_mcmurray/2008/12/17/ftp-clients-part-3-creating-a-global-listener-ftp-site/)

simplest solution would be to run ftp on the 'default website' in IIS